# Choropletic map in Power BI doesn't work well across counties and provinces

Tags: powerbi, bing-maps

In my database model I have on the one hand provinces and on the other hand I have regions.

**Provinces Model:**

[image]
[image]

The first column is the ISO 3166 of the province, then name, latitude, longitude and the ISO 3166 of the region if it belongs to a region.

**Regions Model:**

[image]

The first column is the ISO 3166 of the region, then name, latitude and longitude.

I have created in a PowerBI page a choropletic map by provinces.

I have done the test with 8 countries. France, Germany, Italy, Mexico, Poland, Portugal, Spain and United Kingdom

Countries with Regions: Spain, France, Italy and United Kingdom.

**Configuration map of provinces:**

I have created a field "Location" which is the concatenation of the ISO_PROV + ", " + NAME_PROV.

And in the data category I have put "County"

I also pass the latitude and longitude of the table of provinces.

[image]
[image]

The problem I encounter is the following:

Countries that have regions show me the area on the map very well, but countries that do not have a region such as Germany, Poland or Portugal only paint the city.

[image]

Performing tests I have changed the parameter Data category to "State or province".

[image]

And the following happens to me:

Countries that do not have regions show me very well the marked province.

But the countries that DO have a region I get the wrong areas with erroneous data when I put on top.

[image]

Currently I do not use the iso_region but it is important to understand whyof the difference of maps.

Is there an option to display well-marked provinces whether they have regions or not?

Is it possible to change the field "data category" mediate dax or some other way?

Why if everything is provinces, paint the map differently depending on whether the "data category" field is county or province?